# Split URL query in Swift

Tags: swift, url

I have the following URL query:

```
encodedMessage=PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg%3D%3D&signature=kcig33sdAOAr%2FYYGf5r4HGN
```

How can I split the query to get the of `encodedMessage` and `signature` values?

Comment: URLComponents: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the key value pairs this way:

```
let str = "encodedMessage=PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg%3D%3D&signature=kcig33sdAOAr%2FYYGf5r4HGN"
let arr = str.components(separatedBy:"&")
var data = [String:Any]()
for row in arr {
    let pairs = row.components(separatedBy:"=")
    data[pairs[0]] = pairs[1]
}
let message = data["encodedMessage"]
let sig = data["signature"]
```

I am not sure if that's what you were looking for or not. If it is not, could you please clarify a bit further as to what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it is exaclty what i want but i only need to get the value for encodedMessage and signature. How do i store them into a variable?

Comment: See the edit I made to get the values as variables. Though you could simply extract them from the dictionary as you want as well :)

Answer (score 16):

The right way to achieve this is to work with [*URLComponents*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents):

> A structure designed to parse URLs based on RFC 3986 and to construct
>   URLs from their constituent parts.

By getting the url components [host](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents/1779882-host) string and [query​Items](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents/1779966-queryitems) array, as follows:

```
if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://mydummysite.com?encodedMessage=PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg%3D%3D&signature=kcig33sdAOAr%2FYYGf5r4HGN"), let host = urlComponents.host, let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems {

    print(host) // mydummysite.com

    print(queryItems) // [encodedMessage=PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg==, signature=kcig33sdAOAr/YYGf5r4HGN]
}
```

`queryItems` array contains [URLQuery​Item](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlqueryitem) objects, which have `name` and `value` properties:

```
if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://mydummysite.com?encodedMessage=PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg%3D%3D&signature=kcig33sdAOAr%2FYYGf5r4HGN"),let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems {

    // for example, we will get the first item name and value:
    let name = queryItems[0].name // encodedMessage
    let value = queryItems[0].value // PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg==
}
```

**Also:**

In case of you are getting the query without the full url, I'd suggest to do a pretty simple trick, by adding a dummy host as a prefix to your query string, as follows:

```
let myQuery = "encodedMessage=PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg%3D%3D&signature=kcig33sdAOAr%2FYYGf5r4HGN"
let myDummyUrlString = "http://stackoverflow.com?" + myQuery

if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: myDummyUrlString),let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems {
    // for example, we will get the first item name and value:
    let name = queryItems[0].name // encodedMessage
    let value = queryItems[0].value // PD94bWwgdmVyNlPg==
} else {
    print("invalid url")
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens.. It doesnt return anything when i execute it

Comment: make sure that the used url is a valid one, what are showing in the question is just the query, it is not a full url.

Comment: It is kind of weird to me that you are getting a query without the full url. However, please check the edit.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The above will follow RFC 3986 and will correctly handle all the edge cases - like the initial '?' and so on in a complete URL.

Comment: Brilliant ! thanks for a detailed explanation with a perfect example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I am using to break URLs with `swift5`

```
func breakURL(_ urlString: String) -> URLComponents? {
    // Create a URL from the given urlString
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return nil
    }
    
    // Get the components of the URL
    if let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
        return urlComponents
    } else {
        print("Failed to parse URL components")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Following is the way to use it.

```
if let urlComponents = breakURL("https://www.example.com/path/to/resource?param1=value1&param2=value2") {
    print("Scheme: \(urlComponents.scheme ?? "N/A")") // https
    print("Host: \(urlComponents.host ?? "N/A")") //www.example.com
    print("Path: \(urlComponents.path)") //path/to/resource
    print("Query: \(urlComponents.query ?? "N/A")") //param1=value1&param2=value2
}
```

if you want to break path or query you can get specific value with index number or just put loop on it ...

```
for queryItem in urlComponents.queryItems ?? [] {
    print("\(queryItem.name): \(queryItem.value ?? "N/A")") 
}
```